# Regular expression to replace double semicolon

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace two or more consecutive semicolon with only one semi colon as in the code below, can anyone help me.

```
import re
str='select \n current_date;; \n'
str += ';'
str += 'Select 1 ;  '
str += ';'

print re.sub(';+',';',str)
```

Comment: Your code looks like it works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: the problem with it is the "select 
 current_date; ;Select 1

Comment: and also the last two semi colons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also want to replace double semicolons where there might be some space between them, you could try this regex:

```
import re
str='select \n current_date;; \n'
str += ';'
str += 'Select 1 ;  '
str += ';'

print re.sub('(;\s*)+;',';',str)
```

Output:

```
select 
 current_date;Select 1 ;
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/OYFEP16101)

Comment: thanks, this will serve the purpose , do you think it will be good to convert the multi line string into a single string and search for 2 semi colons ?

Comment: It's not necessary to do that as `\s` will match a newline as well. It would probably only improve what it looked like when your printed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove repetitions of semicolons, `;`:

```
import re
string ='select \n current_date;; \n'
string += ';'
string += 'Select 1 ;  '
string += ';'

print(re.sub(';(\s+);|(;)+',';', string))

>>
select 
 current_date; 
;Select 1 ;
```

This removes semicolons with spaces in between or one or more repetitions of it. The first pattern `;(\s+);` is for semicolons with whitespaces and the second for one or more repetitions, `(;)+`.

Also, do not use Python's namespaces such as `str` for variable names.

**Edit:**
I just realized because of the added newlines this won't return what you want:

The answer given by Nick sorts that out by replacing semicolons with all whitespaces and repetitions.

```
print(re.sub('(;\s*)+;',';',str))
```

*Just for clarity.*